# JQuery - Find images, append caption from attr

Tags: jquery

I'm not (at all) familiar with JQuery and only dip my toe once in a blue moon. However, I have a need that I simply cannot find a quick solution for - despite my conviction that such a quick solution must be available :)

I have a div in which images may be floated amongst the text. I want to scan that div, select all the images therein(if any), give them a class, append a `<p></p>` to them, and enclose both `<img>` and matching `<p>` in their own wrapping div. Into that created paragraph block I then want to place the title attribute of said image.

I've tried Google and here, but both are coated with snippets dealing with plugins, whereas I just want a plug-and-play snippet I can place in my included js file. I have tried piecing together something myself from whats on the JQuery site, but it's a mess.

Any help at all greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Using the answer provided by @Xeon06 below, my completed working solution was as follows:

```
$(".lorem img").each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("inline-img"); 
    $(this).wrap("<div>"); 
    if ($(this).prop("title")!='') {
        $("<p>").text($(this).prop("title")).insertAfter($(this)); 
    }
});

$(".lorem div").each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("inline-img-wrap"); 
});

$(".inline-img").each(function() { 
    var mTop = $(this).css('marginTop');
    var mBottom = $(this).css('marginBottom');
    var mLeft = $(this).css('marginLeft');
    var mRight = $(this).css('marginRight');
    var thisfloat = $(this).css('float');
    $(this).parent().css('marginTop', mTop);
    $(this).css('marginTop', '');
    $(this).parent().css('marginBottom', mBottom);
    $(this).css('marginBottom', '');
    $(this).parent().css('marginLeft', mLeft);
    $(this).css('marginLeft', '');
    $(this).parent().css('marginRight', mRight);
    $(this).css('marginRight', '');
    $(this).parent().css('float', thisfloat );
    $(this).css('float', '');
});
```

The last portion of code was to take the primary positioning attributes of the image (margin and float) and apply them instead to the wrapping div created earlier. I then wiped these values from the images themselves to avoid doubling-up. Excuse the noobish coding!

Comment: You can't actually append anything to an `<img>` tag, but you can append it after the `<img>`.

Comment: If you mean that it would appear immedaitely after the image tag, then that would be fine. Assuming both would be wrapped in a div of their own also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#yourdiv img").each(function() { //Loops through the images in a specific div. $(this) represents the current image in the loop
    $(this).addClass("yourclass"); //Add a class
    $(this).wrap("<div>"); //Add a wrapping div
    $("<p>").text($(this).prop("title")).insertAfter($(this)); //Create a new paragraph with the title property of the image as text and put it after the image (inside our newly created div)
});
```

Tried to explain as best as I could in the comments. [**Here is a live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/QPXAV/).

If there are any questions or you want any clarifications don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I would only change one thing. well, four actually. I would add a var me = $(this) in the beginning and change all the $(this) to "me".

Comment: Works! Thank you kind sir :)

@ Mario, does this substitution improve the speed of such a query?

Comment: @Eamonn That's micro-optimization I wouldn't worry about. A lot of people use `$(this)` throughout functions without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you helper code without seeing the page itself but perhaps you can start by Googling around some of the jQuery methods found in the snippit below.

```
var images = jQuery( '#div_id' ).find( 'img' );
var x = 0, imglen = images.length, pic;
foreach( x = 0; x < imglen; x += 1 ) {
   pic = images[ x ];
   jQuery( pic ).replaceWith( jQuery( "<p>" + pic.attr( 'title' ) + "</p>" ).addClass( 'className' ).append( pic ) );
}
```

Comment: Be careful with [`.attr`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 0):

In order to act on each image in the div (let's assume its id is "myDiv"), you would use the following function:

```
$('#myDiv img').each(function(i) {
    //Do stuff to the image, which can be referred to as $(this)
}
```

Then for each image, do you operation.

I suggest changing the order you describe it, though. The functions you will want to use are `wrap`([doc](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)), `append`([doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/)), and `addClass`([doc](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)). Wrap the image in the new div, append the `<p></p>` to the new div, and append the text to the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way I can think of is this:

```
$('#div_id').find('img').wrap('<div>').after(function() {
    return $('<p>').text($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ey76x/

Comment: Pasted this precisely (changed #div_id to appropriate class name, but no joy. It is within an overall document.ready function.

Comment: It works in the jsFiddle. Perhaps if you added your original HTML structure to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

I found these codes help full to me and did this in easy way with out plugin,

```
$('#portfolio li img').each(function() {
        $("<h4>").text($(this).attr("title")).insertAfter($(this)); }); 
    $('#portfolio li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('h4').slideDown();
    },function(){
        $(this).children('h4').slideUp();
    });
```

hope this helps some one who are looking for simple code  for beginners like me